# How do you show tabs in Zen mode of Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code how to you keep tabs the tabs from hiding when you enter Zen mode?
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Answering this one myself as I've had to do it a few times and Google took too long.

- Open Visual Studio Code settings: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- Tabs should be enabled by default in **non-Zen** mode.
  `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true,`
- Then to show tabs in **Zen** mode.
  `"zenMode.hideTabs": false,`

<sub>**2023 Update**

All settings can now be found [in the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_zen-mode).</sub>

Comment: Here is where you can find all the preferences for **Zen Mode**:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_zen-mode

Comment: Thanks so much, will add that for the changes to work I had to exit and re-enter zen mode.