# Hide top bar in visual studio code (zen mode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, zen

[image]

I have hidden tabs already and disabled some things like line numbers etc. How to get rid of top bar which contains file name `ProfilePrivate.tsx`?

Comment: There's an open issue for being able to hide the buttons in the tab bar (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46403).  I haven't see anything regarding removing the file name.

Answer (score 10):

I've found a solution.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33607#issuecomment-424193133

1. Install Custom CSS & JS vscode plugin
2. Create file `/Users/(yourusername)/.vscode.css` and paste there: `.title.show-file-icons { display: none !important; }`
3. Change vscode settings adding: `"vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///Users/(yourusername)/.vscode.css"]`
4. Press `CMD + Shift + P` and write Enable custom css and js
5. Restart vscode

It should hide top bar.

Comment: Still works in 2020. I just wanted to hide this in fullscreen mode, so instead i used `.fullscreen .title.show-file-icons {display: none !important;}`.

Comment: @NilsLindemann Although it hides the top bar, it leaves empty space at the bottom. https://i.imgur.com/JdlpoOd.jpg

Comment: @tejasvi88 This can unfortunately not be fully fixed, but I tried my best, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67298583/1658543).

Answer (score 1):

Hide the top bar using a command from command palette:

Install: [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler), [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) extensions.

Add this to your settings.json:

```json
  "zenMode.restore": true,
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "toggleUltraZen",
        "sequence": [
            "workbench.action.toggleZenMode",
            "settings.cycle.ultraZen",
            "workbench.action.reloadWindow",
        ]
    },
  ],
  "settings.cycle": [{
    "id": "ultraZen",
    "overrideWorkspaceSettings": false,
    "values": [
      {
        "customizeUI.stylesheet": {}
      },
      {
        "customizeUI.stylesheet": {
          ".title.show-file-icons": "display: none !important;",
        },
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

To use this, from command palette:

1. `Multi command: Execute multi command`

   - choose `toggleUltraZen` and hit Enter

Note that the first command will reload the window.

I also use (for coding):

```json
  "zenMode.fullScreen": false,
  "zenMode.centerLayout": false,
  "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": false,
  "zenMode.hideStatusBar": false,
```

which you might pick and choose based on your needs (they are accessible from the Settings UI).

[image: example of ultra zen UI]

Comment: hrrm... not working for me but i'm curious if we're discussing the same menubar? https://i.imgur.com/GaFJNTs.png

Answer (score 1):

This is what one can do to improve ZEN mode.

(At the end there is still a region at the top which will lap over the code when scrolling. It is unfortunately not possible (at least for me) to fix it with CSS, because the height of the editor gets dynamically calculated with JavaScript. Probably this can be done with an extension like [Monkey Patch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch), but I did not test it.)

First, choose from these standard settings, to be put into the settings.json. Some settings require a restart, e.g. the `editor.scrollbar` settings. Some settings also affect the display when not in ZEN mode.

```json
{
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "editor.codeLens": false,
    "editor.folding": false,
    "editor.foldingHighlight": false,
    "editor.highlightActiveIndentGuide": false,
    "editor.lineNumbers": "off",
    "editor.matchBrackets": "never",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false,
    "editor.minimap.showSlider": "always",
    "editor.occurrencesHighlight": false,
    "editor.overviewRulerBorder": false,
    "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
    "editor.renderLineHighlight": "none",
    "editor.rulers": [],
    "editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
    "editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden",
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
    "editor.selectionHighlight": false,
    "scm.diffDecorations": "none",
    "window.title": "${activeEditorLong} ${dirty}",
    "window.titleSeparator": " – ",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1.3,
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        // see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color
    },
    "workbench.editor.showTabs": false,
    "zenMode.centerLayout": true,
    "zenMode.fullScreen": true,
    "zenMode.hideLineNumbers": true,
    "zenMode.hideStatusBar": true,
    "zenMode.hideTabs": true,
    "zenMode.restore": false,
}
```

I found these settings in these answers: [Xixixao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876039/1658543), [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481346/1658543), [2](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/vscode-tips-remove-the-highlighted-line), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63323077/1658543), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880845/1658543), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59493115/1658543), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38147289/1658543), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49196147/1658543), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43973209/1658543).

If that is not enough, append the following CSS rules to the `workbench.desktop.main.css`. This file is usually located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench`. If it is not, use *Help* → *Toggle Developer Tools* to figure out where it resides, or [search system wide](https://www.voidtools.com/) for it.

After a restart, VSCode will give a warning that your installation is "corrupt". That's ok. Choose "don't show message again". Alternatively, you may also try doing it with an add-on like [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui). I did not test that.

```css
.fullscreen .decorationsOverviewRuler {
    display:none !important;
}

.fullscreen .invisible.scrollbar.vertical {
    display:none !important;
}

/* You dont need this if you have "zenMode.centerLayout": false, */
.fullscreen .monaco-split-view2.separator-border>.monaco-scrollable-element>.split-view-container>.split-view-view:not(:first-child):before {
    background:transparent !important;
}

/* Do not use these if you have "zenMode.hideTabs": false, */
.fullscreen .title.show-file-icons {
    display: none !important;
}
.fullscreen .editor-container {
    margin-top:34px !important;
}
.fullscreen .scroll-decoration {
    display:none !important;
}
```

I found these tweaks by inspecting the source using *Help* → *Toggle Developer Tools*.

Screenshot before/after:

[image]