# How can I remove left vertical lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have searched the whole web but cannot find where to remove these two types of vertical lines on the left side. I specifically mean the colored thick vertical line (marked with red box) and the thin grey vertical line (also marked with red box).

If someone could tell me that would be awesome! Thanks a lot.

[image: Remove Lines in VS Code - How?]

Comment: The thin gray lines are indent guides - see the answer below to get rid of them.  The thicker colored lines are related to your source control - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43969277/how-can-you-disable-gutter-indicators-in-vs-code/43973209#43973209

Answer (score 89):

Go to the menu `Code->Preference->Settings` and search for `"renderIndentGuides"`. The complete setting should appear as:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Change it to `false`.

UPDATE:

Keys had changed since v1.61 - on later version set the following instead:

```
"editor.guides.indentation": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings and follow the numbers in the picture.

[image: Pic 1]