# visual studio code import custom css and js extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to install custom styles in order to have different fonts for classes and attributes in visual studio code.

I installed the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) extension, and followed the guide but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I've tried. I created a file `styles.css` where I put this code:

```css
.mtk1,
.mtk2,
.mtk8,
.mtk9,
.mtk10,
.mtk12,
.mtk11,
.mtk7,
.mtk3,
.mtk13,
.mtk16 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  font-family: "Indie Flower";
  font-size: 1em;

}

.mtk7,
.mtk4 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

/*
For the tab titles.
*/
.monaco-icon-label-description-container .label-name {
  font-family: "Indie Flower";
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

.tabs-container .monaco-icon-label-description-container .label-name,
.sidebar .monaco-icon-label-description-container .label-name,
.quick-open-row .monaco-icon-label-description-container .label-name {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe WPC,Segoe UI,HelveticaNeue-Light,Ubuntu,Droid Sans,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Then in `settings.json` I added the following settings:

```json
{
  "vscode_custom_css.imports": ["file:///home/mat/vscode_extensions/styles.css"],
  "vscode_custom_css.policy": true
}
```

I took the path by typing inside this directory `pwd`, so it should be correct path. However, it still doesn't want to apply styles, neither `fontFamily` nor `fontSize`.

Does anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run VSCode as Administrator and then `Enable CSS in JS`.

Example path to VSCode located in Applications:
`sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron`

And don't forget to install all those custom fonts to your Mac device.

Comment: And recently there was an update for VSCode which changed classes on elements. So your custom css will probably not match what you are expecting from it.

Comment: it works! The problem was that I didn't run it as a administrator... Thank you so much:)

Comment: Btw if in the future you modify your styles, to apply them you need to hit `ctrl+shift+p` (show all commands) -> `Enable Custom CSS and JS` and then restart vscode!

Answer (score 7):

**Extension didn't work for me but** For what it's worth....while i was messing with this...if you go to the help menu, toggle the Developer Tools....
It will
Check the network tab > you will see there is one css file that vscode loads up.

`file:///Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css`

I went into this file and directly edited the css directly...

since i already had a css file that i intended to use with this extension...

`@import url("file:///Users/adrian/.vscode/vs-code-styles.css");`

Reload & Problem solved.

For example, i love my font but all i wanted was the tag to by with a different font-family then the attributes. After some trial and error, this did it. Mileage may very depending on whether or not vscode is changing these classes all the time.

```
span:not(.mtk1) + .mtki, span:not(.mtk1) + .mtk6{
    font-family: 'Courier New' !important;
}
```

Comment: **WARNING** - I wouldn't do this.  When I modified the css file, on the next launch I got the warning ["Your Code installation appears to be corrupt.  Please reinstall"](https://i.imgur.com/fAggsXi.png). They might have a checksum to prevent malicious tampering

Comment: @KyleMit That seems to be normal when you're loading your own CSS. If you use the Custom CSS and JS Loader extension you get the same warning.

Comment: @nerrons, I've been using [Customize UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.customize-ui) and [Monkey Patch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iocave.monkey-patch) and haven't run into the same issue

Comment: @KyleMit Yes those two are fine, but the Custom CSS and JS Loader extension specifically states that it will trigger the "corrupt" message in their README. I'm not sure why though

Comment: Much better than giving admin rights to a random extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good css configuration for the above mentioned extension.

PS: Make sure to update the font names in the below mentioned code.

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* activitybar-icon-extension */
.monaco-workbench .activitybar > .content :not(.monaco-menu) > .monaco-action-bar .action-label:not(.codicon) {
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
 opacity: 0.50;
}

/* activitybar-icon-inbuilt */
.monaco-workbench .activitybar > .content :not(.monaco-menu) > .monaco-action-bar .action-label.codicon {
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
 opacity: 0.50;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* widget-find */
.monaco-findInput .monaco-inputbox {
 font-family: var(--font-type-m);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

.search-view .query-details.more h4 {
 font-family: var(--font-type-m);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

.monaco-editor .find-widget .monaco-findInput .input {
 font-family: var(--font-type-m);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

.monaco-editor .find-widget > .find-part {
 font-family: var(--font-type-m);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* list-text */
.monaco-highlighted-label {
 font-family: var(--font-type-m);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

/* list-line-height-compensate */
.monaco-list > .monaco-scrollable-element > .monaco-list-rows > .monaco-list-row {
 transform: scale(1, 1);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* explorer */
.explorer-folders-view > .monaco-list > .monaco-scrollable-element > .monaco-list-rows span {
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

.explorer-folders-view > .monaco-list > .monaco-scrollable-element > .monaco-list-rows {
 margin-left: -12px;
}

.monaco-list-row[aria-expanded] {
 opacity: 0.5;
}

.monaco-list-row[aria-expanded=true] {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.monaco-list-row.selected {
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* sidebar-1-header */
.monaco-workbench .part.sidebar > .title > .title-label h2 {
 font-family: var(--font-type-l);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* sidebar-2-header */
.monaco-action-bar .action-label {
 font-family: var(--font-type-l);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* sidebar-3-header */
.monaco-pane-view .pane > .pane-header h3.title {
 font-family: var(--font-type-l);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
 text-transform: lowercase;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* tab */
.monaco-workbench .part.editor > .content .editor-group-container > .title .tabs-container > .tab .tab-label a,
.monaco-workbench .part.editor > .content .editor-group-container > .title .title-label a {
 font-family: var(--font-type-l);
 font-size: var(--font-size-m);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* statusbar-text */
.monaco-workbench .part.statusbar {
 font-family: var(--font-type-n);
 font-size: var(--font-size-n);
}

/* statusbar-icon */
.monaco-workbench .part.statusbar > .items-container > .statusbar-item span.codicon {
 font-size: var(--font-size-n);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* z */
.mac {
 --monaco-monospace-font: var(--font-type-n);
 font-family: var(--font-type-n);
 font-size: var(--font-size-n);
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
:root {
 --font-size-l: 27.50px;
 --font-size-m: 22.00px;
 --font-size-n: 16.50px;
 --font-type-l: 'HarayKrsna-Extrabold-Ultra-Condensed', monospace;
 --font-type-m: 'HarayKrsna-Ultra-Condensed', monospace;
 --font-type-n: 'HarayKrsna-Extralight-Ultra-Condensed', monospace;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* fixes border */
.monaco-workbench .part > .composite.title {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #808080FF;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**